# I can not use multi-layer perceptron in Weka

Tags: neural-network, weka, multiplayer, perceptron

This is my data-set:

```
@RELATION departman_tahmini

@ATTRIBUTE tarih {1.01.2017} 
@ATTRIBUTE saat {03:00,06:00,09:00,10:00,11:00,11:30,13:00,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30}
@ATTRIBUTE hastaneler {X1, X2}
@ATTRIBUTE hasta_sikayeti STRING
@ATTRIBUTE temel_neden STRING
@ATTRIBUTE class {Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5, Y6}

@DATA

1.01.2017,03:00,X1,Yanık,Yanık,Y1
1.01.2017,06:00,X1,Bacak_şişmesi,Kırık,Y1
1.01.2017,09:00,X1,Ateş,Üşütme,Y3
1.01.2017,09:00,X1,Ateş,Diş_çıkarma,Y3
1.01.2017,10:00,X1,Baygınlık,Yüksekten_düşme,Y1
1.01.2017,10:00,X1,Bel_ağrısı,Fıtık,Y5
1.01.2017,11:00,X1,Ayak_ağrısı,kırılma,Y6
1.01.2017,11:00,X1,Karın_ağrısı,Gıda_zehirlenmesi,Y5
1.01.2017,11:30,X1,İshal,Mikrobik,Y5
1.01.2017,13:00,X1,Bayılma,Düşük_tansiyon,Y1
1.01.2017,14:00,X1,Soğukalgınlığı,Üşütme,Y2
1.01.2017,14:30,X1,Ateş,Üşütme,Y3
1.01.2017,15:00,X1,Yüksek_tansiyon,KBY,Y4
1.01.2017,15:00,X1,Yüksek_tansiyon,Damar_sorunları,Y4
1.01.2017,15:00,X1,Ayak_ağrısı,Kırık_ayak_parmağı,Y6
1.01.2017,15:30,X1,İshal,Üşütme,Y5
1.01.2017,15:30,X1,Burun_akması,Üşütme,Y2
```

But I can not use multi-layer perceptron in Weka. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have some attribute issues.
tarih has only one value, and so will be useless for prediction.
saat is a nominal variable,but has 11 values for the 17 instances.This would likely result in overfitting.
hastaneler has only one value, and so will be useless for prediction.
hasta_sikayeti is a string attribute, not used in mult-layer perceptron. Change it to nominal if it can be used.
temel_neden is also string.
There are five classes, but 17 instances; too few, IMO

In short, your data set as shown isn't suitable for a multi-layer perceptron, or really any predictive analytics. Weka is doing you a favor.

Comment: thank you @zbicyclist .
in fact I have to use string value as input. But you says "Change it to nominal if it can be used". So, 
Can not I use a string value if I want to use multilayer perceptron? How can I change the nominal value?

Comment: In the Explorer, Preprocess tab, Filter, Choose, Unsupervised, Attribute, StringToNominal.  This will make StringToNominal show up in the bar to the right of the Choose button. Right click StringToNominal to bring up the weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.  In the attributeRange box put 4-5 to indicate the 4th and 5th attribute. Click OK to close the dialog box. Then click the Apply button on the right to apply the filter.

Comment: But you will still have problems because the attributes have too many different values relative to the size of the data -- e.g. there are 17 instances, but 13 distinct values for temel-neden. You will need to combine those to a smaller set or you will either not be able to run the perceptron or will overfit.

Comment: I increase my data, you are right. I did not know data preprocessing. I am working on this topic. @zbicyclist